# How to get SPServer's machine name?

Tags: sharepoint

Normally in SharePoint, one SPServer'name equals machine name, but if we use

```
stsadm.exe -o renameserver
       -oldservername <oldServerName>
       -newservername <newServerName>
```

[image]

to change the server name, , then can anybody tell how to get the agent name that locate the SPServer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have got the answer, please refer to http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010general/thread/73851c5d-1a6d-491e-959f-545be86326da for details.

thanks

Comment: Hi Daniel, this is a link-only answer and risks losing all value when the link is broken. Consider including the significant information directly in the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you use powershell, you could use either of these two commands:

> [System.Net.Dns]::GetHostName()
>
> $env:COMPUTERNAME

Comment: Hi, sorry for the misunderstanding, I just want to get the agent name that locate the SPServer.